# Getting a value back from a child component after it is routed in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to react and currently I am stuck in a scenario where I have 2 components,

1. Launcher Component
2. Developer component

In this, Launcher Component is called first.From that on button click it routes to Developer component. I want to pass a value back from Developer component to Launcher component after routing.

Launcher.js

```
class LauncherApp extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.developerMode = this.developerMode.bind(this)
      }

    developerMode(){
        this.props.history.push('/dev') //routes to developer component
       }

    render() {
       return (
    <div>
             <List>
                <ListItem
                onClick={this.developerMode}>Developer<ListItem/>
             </List>
    </div>
     );
  }
      }
```

Developer.js

```
class DeveloperMode extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
               this.state = {
                  url:'Prod'
                };
          }

           handleChange(event) {
            this.setState({
              url: event.target.value
            });
          } 
            handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var env=this.state.url;
              this.props.signOut();
             }
render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <h3>Select Environment </h3>
        <RadioButtonGroup name="selectURL" defaultSelected="Prod"  onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <RadioButton
            value="Prod"
            label="Production"

          />
          <RadioButton
            value="Dev"
            label="Development"

          />
          <RadioButton
          value="Test"
          label="Testing"

        />
        </RadioButtonGroup>
        <RaisedButton label="Save" onClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
        }
```

Routes.js

```
const Routes = () => (


      <Router>             
          <div>
          <Route component={LauncherApp}/>
              <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={"/"} component={ApplicationList} />
                    <Route path={"/dev"} component={DeveloperMode} />
              </Switch>
         </div>

  </Router>

);
```

Is there any way that I can get the value 'url' from developer component when it is routed in Launcher.js

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use redux, but you have not specified that you want to use it.
So you can use this other way, which I would not prefer over redux normally.
You can pass a function as props in the router

```
    <Route exact path='/dev' render={(props) => (
                                         <Developer {...props} getURL={this.getURLFromDeveloper}/>
                                        )}/>
    <Route path='/' render={(props) => (
                                         <Launcher {...props} URL={this.state.URL}/>
                                        )}/>
```

(The way to pass the function can change depending on how you implement the router, which you have not shown here). So the getURLFromDeveloper() function can be connected to the state of the class rendering the routes.

```
   getURLFromDeveloper(URL){
      this.setState({URL})
   }
```

To be clear, the parent of both these components has the state variable URL and also the function getURLFromDeveloper(), which is passed as a prop in the router component of Developer. When the URL changes in the Developer component, call

```
    this.props.getURL(<new value of the URL>);
```

this will call the getURLFromDeveloper function of the parent which will change the state of the parent and start a rerender.

Now the rerender will be on the path "/dev" which is the last path you pushed in the history, so you have to go to the path which renders the Launcher component to access the new value of this.props.URL

Edit: Since you have a separate Routes.js file. You have to define the getURLFromDeveloper() function and the state "URL" where you render the Route Component in your app.

```
    render(){
      return (
          <Routes getURL={this.getURLFromDeveloper} URL={this.state.URL}/>
      )}
```

In Routes.js

```
  const Routes = (props) => (
   <Router>             
      <div>
      <Route component={LauncherApp}/>
          <Switch>
                 <Route exact path='/dev' render={(props) => (
                                     <Developer {...props} getURL={props.getURL}/>
                                    )}/>
                <Route path='/' render={(props) => (
                                     <Launcher {...props} URL={props.URL}/>
                                    )}/>
          </Switch>
     </div>
   </Router>
 );
```

Comment: Is this function name _this.props.getURL_ same as _getURLFromDeveloper_

Comment: Also i have updated the question.Please check the routes.js and see how can function be passed.

Comment: Yes, they are the same. When you write this <Developer {...props} getURL={getURLFromDeveloper}/> you pass the getURLFromDeveloper () as props to the the Developer component. Inside the Developer component you can access it by using  "this.props.getURL"